# Ubuntu distro not installed [The system cannot execute the specified program]

Tags: ubuntu, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed WSL and enabled it using instructions from this [site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-on-server). Then I tried installing Ubuntu distro with command

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
```

It shows distro is installed properly and tries to launch the Ubuntu, but after some time it fails with error

[WSL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqAu9.png)

Then after this, when I run a command

```
wsl -l
```

to check what distros are installed I get a message that no distros are installed.

How can I solve this issue? Just a remark that I don't have Microsoft Store access on this computer. I tried installing it manually from a appx package, but that did not work as well.

EDIT:
I'm using Windows 10, build 19044.1645

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment; the vital information that is required is the exact build of Windows you are running.  Be sure you are downloading the package from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distributions) instead of another source[.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-on-server)

Comment: I downloaded the package from the suggested source and tried installing it manually as instructed by the microsoft docs (given in the first link above). However, when I start the application after installation with Ubuntu.exe command then it says "The system cannot execute the specified program.". I think it was trying to update Ubuntu via Microsoft store, but as already mentioned we don't have Store access (or internet access in general) on this computer.

Comment: Also, it might be worth noting that we got Ubuntu working before using the same steps to install Ubuntu manually from appx file. However, as it was installed into wrong directory (Downloads) then we deleted it there and tried to install it under C: drive, but now the same steps don't work.

Comment: You should update your question with regards to the error you received, there are existing questions with answers to that particular error